# Как определить пол человека в VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Задан массив из ФИО. Нужно определить пол каждого человека по последней гласной букве.
Вот код, он работает, но выводить только мужской пол

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim s, i, a As Integer
Dim h, g As String
gls = ("а""я""о""е""ё""у""ю""ы""и""э")
For a = 1 To 10
    h = Cells(a, 1)
    i = (InStr(h, " "))
    g = i - 1
    If gls = g Then
        Cells(a, 3) = "жен"
    Else
        Cells(a, 3) = "муж"
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` - строковая переменная, сюда Вы хотели записать букву, но записываете число:

```
g = i - 1
```

А надо было взять символ, находящийся  на позиции `i - 1`

Даже если в `g` получили каким-то образом букву, то дальнейшее сравнение ничего не дает:

```
If gls = g Then
```

Вернее, всегда вернет `False`, т.к. символ не может быть равен тексту из нескольких символов.

Попутные ошибки или "кривость писанины".

В `VBA` тип нужно указывать для каждой переменной, иначе тип - `Variant`

Переменным нужно давать имена, по которым легче ориентироваться в коде. Однобуквенные - обычно для счетчиков.

*"а""я""о""е""ё""у""ю""ы""и""э"* - в тексте сдвоенные кавычки означают наличие кавычки, т.е. в переменную записываете строку *"а"я"о"е"ё"у"ю"ы"и"э"*

`Cells(i, 1)` - по умолчанию подразумевается значение ячейки, но такая запись также означает диапазон. Для избежания возможных ошибок правильнее явно указывать, что хотите получить.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sLetter As String, sName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Const cSymbols As String = "аяоеёуюыиэ"
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        sName = Cells(i, 1).Value
        sLetter = Mid$(sName, InStr(sName, " ") - 1, 1)
        
        If InStr(cSymbols, sLetter) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "жен"
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "муж"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Весь набор гласных для этой задачи не нужен. Достаточно знать, что мужские отчества заканчиваются на "ч" (не всегда, но в подавляющем большинстве случаев)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim oCell As Range
Dim sFullName As String
    Set oCell = [A2]
    Do While True
        sFullName = Trim(oCell.Text)
        If sFullName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        If Right(sFullName, 1) = "." Then ' На случай если вместо полного ФИО только инициалы
            oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "???"
        ElseIf LCase(Right(sFullName, 1)) = "ч" Then
            oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "муж"
        Else
            oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "жен"
        End If
        Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Тоже вариант. Для решения каких-то моментов можно использовать варианты в одной процедуре